# Cannot display records in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I am just new to WPF and I am having problems displaying my record. It seems that my records are "shy" when it comes to displaying them, even though I have all my records already.

Code for my App.xaml.cs:

```cs
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        Window1 window = new Window1();
        var viewModel = new Window1ViewModel();        

        window.PHGrid.ItemsSource = viewModel.ViewModels;
        window.Show();
    }
```

Code for Window1ViewModel:

```cs
public class Window1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly DAPHContrib _contribRepository;
    private ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> _viewModelBases;

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ViewModels
    {
        get
        {
            if (_viewModelBases == null)
            {
                _viewModelBases = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
            }
            return _viewModelBases;
        }
    }

    public Window1ViewModel()
    {
        _contribRepository = new DAPHContrib();
        //Create instance of our view model to add it in our collection

        PHContribViewModel viewModel = new PHContribViewModel(_contribRepository);
        ViewModels.Add(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Here's my Window1.xaml **UPDATED**:

```
<Window x:Class="Wabby_App.Views.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Wabby_App.ViewModels" 
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Wabby_App.Views" 
    Title="Utos ng mahal ko" 
    Height="300" 
    Width="300">

<Grid>
    <DataGrid 
        AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
        Height="200" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        Name="PHGrid" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Width="200"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}"/>

</Grid>
```

Output:

[image: My records are "shy"]

Hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Does your `PHContribViewModel` have public Properties ? Make sure that there are no public fields but public properties in `PHContribViewModel`. Other than this, the solution @Ekk suggested below should work just fine.

Comment: Hi @AngelWPF! Yes I do have. My public property is `public ObservableCollection<PHContrib_Entity> PHContribEntities { get; private set; }` Upon breakpoint, I see the records retrieved there. :)

Comment: But thats the problem isnt it. `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` works for primitive type properties inside the `PHContribViewModel`. How can you expect a property `PHContribViewModel.PHContribEntities` which is of type  `ObservableCollection<PHContrib_Entity>` would render the columns for you?

Comment: I'm quite lost. So how should I render my records? I've set my `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and I still have my records when I call `PHContribViewModel viewModel = new PHContribViewModel(_contribRepository);`. Where should I now check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your comments you have view models collection (`ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>`)

and inside each of these view model base instances (`PHContribViewModel`) you have another collection `ObservableCollection<PHContrib_Entity>`.

Hence you have two levels of nested collections and one datagrid to map. This wont work as it is. For this you would need to flatten this 2 level hierarchy of collections into one list of type `ObservableCollection<PHContrib_Entity>`.

Use LINQ to do that...

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
    base.OnStartup(e);
    Window1 window = new Window1();
    var viewModel = new Window1ViewModel();
    window.PHGrid.ItemsSource
     = viewModel.ViewModels.SelectMany(vm => vm.PHContribEntities).ToList();
    window.Show();
}
```

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: So you're saying that instead of using the Window1ViewModel class, I should use the PHContribViewModel right?

Comment: I am not sur what your previous comment means, as far as I know, I think that you expect `ObservableCollection<PHContrib_Entity>` to be rendered on the data grid. But it is part of each view model base. So you would need to flatten it out into a single list of `ObservableCollection<PHContrib_Entity>`.

Comment: What I'm trying to render is `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>` which has my records from `PHContribViewModel`.

Comment: Did you try the code I told you above? Does it give you what you want?

Comment: I tried it, but id does not have the .SelectMany extension method.

Comment: Did u include \ using `System.Linq` in the top of your `App` class?

Comment: Wait! I sort of got what you said. I think you're saying is this: "Why do I need to have my ObservableCollection in one class of ViewModel then use another ObservableCollection in another ViewModel?" Am I right?

Comment: Yes and please do try to add that `System.Linq` namespace  on top of your App class and see if the code works. Coz it works for me!

Comment: Actually, what I did was that I did this in my Window1ViewModel constructor `_contrib = new ObservableCollection<PHContrib_Entity>(_contribRepository.GetAllPHContrib());` Thanks for all your help @AngelWPF and @Ekk

Answer (score 1):

Your View (Window1) is not binding to ViewModel, it's just setting the control's ItemsSource to a property of the ViewModel which is an incorrect way to implement MVVM. What you need to do is set [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) of Window1 to instance of ViewModel (Bind View to ViewModel). So, you need to update your code in the `OnStartup` method.

**from**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    Window1 window = new Window1();
    var viewModel = new Window1ViewModel();        

    window.PHGrid.ItemsSource = viewModel.ViewModels;
    window.Show();
}
```

**to**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    Window1 window = new Window1();
    var viewModel = new Window1ViewModel();        

    window.DataContext = viewModel;
    window.Show();
}
```

**Update**

You also need to set ItemsSource property of datagrid to property in ViewModel

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding ViewModels} ..
```

Comment: I tried it but no records were displayed. I checked by viewModel and it has all the records i need.

Comment: I just update my answer, you need to bind DataGrid ItemsSource to property in ViewModel.

Comment: Still nothing comes out. Just the same as my output picture. But I have my records coming from my Entity Framework.

Comment: Does is show any error in output window? BTW, please use debugger to check `DataContext` of `Windows1` is instance of Window1ViewModel. Also check `ItemsSource={Binding ViewModels}` is spell correctly.

Comment: It is spelled correctly. It gets from the property of the Window1ViewModel class. regarding the error, i don't know if this is an error: `'WPF MVVM Application.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'` But other than that, no error has occurred. :)